# How to implement alphabetical Section RecyclerView in android without any external library?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Hello all am new for android development am trying to make section recyclerview header like items must comes under first charc how can i achieve this so far i have done this with third party library now i like to do it myself please someone help me how to do this here what i have tried before:

```
public class accountheader extends StatelessSection implements View.OnClickListener{
    private accountheader.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    String title;
    List<AccountModel> listobj;
    Context context;
    public accountheader(String title, List<AccountModel> list, Context context) {
        super(R.layout.section_ex1_header, R.layout.recyclerviewitem);
        this.title = title;
        this.listobj = list;
        this.context=context;
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(final accountheader.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }


    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return listobj.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        TextView companyname=viewHolder.CompanyName;
        TextView companygroup=viewHolder.CompanyGroup;
        TextView acm=viewHolder.AccountManager;
        TextView companytype=viewHolder.CompanyType;
        ImageView caption=viewHolder.caption;
        viewHolder.click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, AccountView.class);
                int  name=listobj.get(position).getId();
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Log.d("n",String.valueOf(name));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        companyname.setText(listobj.get(position).getCompanyName());
        companygroup.setText(listobj.get(position).getCompanyGroup());
        acm.setText(listobj.get(position).getAccountManagerText());
        ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.DEFAULT;
        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound((listobj.get(position).getCompanyName().substring(0,1)).toUpperCase(), generator.getRandomColor());
        viewHolder.caption.setImageDrawable(drawable);
  }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;

        headerHolder.tvTitle.setText(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.getParent();
        int   position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(v);
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

            this.onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position);
        }

    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(int position);
    }
}
class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

     final TextView tvTitle;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    }
}

class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     View click;
     TextView CompanyName;
     TextView CompanyGroup;
     TextView AccountManager;
     TextView CompanyType;
     ImageView caption;
     ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
         click=itemView;
        CompanyName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        CompanyGroup=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.middle);
        AccountManager=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.footer);
        CompanyType=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        caption=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }

}
```

This is how i implemented in activity:

```
  SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();
        accountheader Accountheader=null;
        for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++) {
            List<AccountModel> contacts = getContactsWithLetter(alphabet,list);
            Accountheader=new accountheader(String.valueOf(alphabet), contacts,getApplicationContext());
            if (contacts.size() > 0) {
                sectionAdapter.addSection(Accountheader);
            }
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);

    private List<AccountModel> getContactsWithLetter(char letter,List<AccountModel>list) {
        List<AccountModel> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AccountModel accountModel:list) {
            if (accountModel.getCompanyGroup().charAt(0) == letter) {
                contacts.add(accountModel);
            }
        }
        return contacts;
    }
```

How can i achieve this without any third party library can someone please guide me: